# Parse nested XML nodes in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I have XML file like this:

```
<catalog>
   <category>
      <books>
         <book>
            <id>book1</id>
            <description>short description</description>
            <pages>number of pages</pages>
            <author>Anonymous</author>
            <name>Book title</name>
         </book>
         <book>
            <id>book2</id>
            <description>short description</description>
            <pages>number of pages</pages>
            <author>Anonymous</author>
            <name>Book title</name>
         </book>
      </books>
   </category>
   <category>
      <books>
         <book>
            <id>book3</id>
            <description>short description</description>
            <pages>number of pages</pages>
            <author>Anonymous</author>
            <name>Book title</name>
         </book>
      </books>
   </category>
</catalog>
```

And I need an ArrayList with Categories and ArrayList with Books. Here are my Book and Category classes:

```
public class Book 
{
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private String pages;
    private String author;
    private String name;
}
public class Category {
    private ArrayList<Book> books;
    private String name;
}
```

What is the easiest way to do this? Using only android libraries and stuff would be better than using some libraries not for commercial use for my task. I tried some DOM parsers, but it didn't work good.

Comment: what have done so far ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it can easily be done using **dom** parser. Here is a stand alone java program to parse your XML file. I am printing values in standard output you can modify it to use in your android application.

```
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
            File fXmlFile = new File("books");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            // iterate through <category> tags
            NodeList categoryList = doc.getElementsByTagName("category");
            for (int categoryNo=0;categoryNo<categoryList.getLength();categoryNo++) {

                Element categoryNode = (Element)categoryList.item(categoryNo);

                System.out.println("Category No  " +categoryNo);

                //iterate through  <books> tags
                NodeList booksList = categoryNode.getElementsByTagName("books");
                for (int booksNo=0;booksNo<booksList.getLength();booksNo++) {

                    Element books = (Element)booksList.item(0);

                    // iterate through <book> tags
                    NodeList bookList = books.getElementsByTagName("book");
                    for(int bookNo=0;bookNo<bookList.getLength();bookNo++) {
                        Element bookElement = (Element)bookList.item(bookNo);

                        System.out.println(bookElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent());
                        System.out.println(bookElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());
                        System.out.println(bookElement.getElementsByTagName("pages").item(0).getTextContent());
                        System.out.println(bookElement.getElementsByTagName("author").item(0).getTextContent());
                        System.out.println(bookElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [android xml pull parser](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html), this page has examples too
(it is a SAX parser)